# dataframe has a column as dictionary.How to convert it in columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, data-science

Df below has columns which consist a dictionary of the name, gender, and net_salary. The dictionary has many columns and their corresponding values. i need to convert that dictionary in columns form.

```
 index    columns
 9        {"name": "namo     ", "gender": "MALE", "net_salary":...
 10       {"name": "pappu", "gender": "MALE", "net_salary":...
 11       {"name": "Deepak", "gender": "MALE", "net_sala...
 12       {"name": "Arun", "gender": "MALE", "net_salary...
                                                       {}
```

i want output in this form.

```
 index    name    gender       net_salary
 9        namo     MALE          151515
 10       pappu    MALE          151454
 11       Deepak   MALE          42512
 12       Arun     MALE          51654
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`

Answer (score 1):

You need to first slice the column that consists of dicts, and then create a new dataframe of those dicts.

```
columnsList = list(dframe["columns"])
sub_dframe = pd.DataFrame(columnsList)
result = pd.concat([dframe["index"],sub_dframe], axis=1)
```

Comment: and how this will work if two dfs have no common values to merger on?

Comment: @mad_ oh my bad. I confused merge and concat.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columns': [{"name": "namo", "gender": "MALE", "net_salary":151515}, 
                           {"name": "pappu", "gender": "MALE", "net_salary":151454}]}, index=[9,10])


print(df['columns'].apply(pd.Series))
```

Output:

```
    name gender  net_salary
9   namo   MALE      151515
10  pappu   MALE      151454
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do somethings like this (python 3):

```
df["name"] = [*map(lambda x: x["name"],df["columns"])]
df["gender"] = [*map(lambda x: x["gender"],df["columns"])]
df["salary"] = [*map(lambda x: x["net_salary"],df["columns"])]
```

You can then delete the original column if it bothers you.

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Strange, I don't get this error, using a df that replicates your example. Maybe you built the df differently in a way.

Answer (score 0):

A crisp solution could be

```
pd.concat([df,df['columns'].apply(pd.Series)],axis=1).drop('columns',axis=1)
```